# How to mask out first 2 MSB bytes of a 64-bit number?

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, byte

I have a `64-bit unsigned integer`. Which contains `0s` in the first two MSB bytes. How can I mask out that first two MSB bytes?

```
uint64 value;
value = 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 1101 1111 1010 1110 1111 1111 1111 0101 
0101 1101 1101;
uint48 answer;
answer = 0000 1101 1111 1010 1110 1111 1111 1111 0101 
0101 1101 1101;
```

In the above example, the value is a 64-bit number. I want the answer to contain all the bits other than first 2 bytes. So, that I can pack the `answer` in a byte array of size `6`. How can I achieve this in `C`?

Comment: If the two MSB contain zeroes, you don't need to do anything.

Comment: @Barmar I want to mask out the first 2 bytes. So, I can pack the remaining 48 bits into a byte array of size 6!

Comment: make a union with your uint64 value and a byte array

Comment: Do you have a specific byte order in mind for your array? Big endian, little endian, same as source?

Comment: @Gerhardh The byte order is big-endian.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mask it with 48 1-bits: `0xffffffffffff`

```
uint64_t value = <something>;
uint48_t answer = src & 0xffffffffffff;
```

But if you know the 2 MSB are zeroes, you don't need to do any masking, just assign the variables:

```
uint48_t answer = value;
```

To store them in a byte array, shift by the appropriate number of bytes and mask with `0xff` to get a single byte.

```
uint8_t bytes[6];
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    bytes[i] = (value >> (40 - 8 * i)) & 0xff;
}
```

You can use either the original 64-bit value or the 48-bit value, this works for any size at least 6 bytes.

Comment: @Barmar I am a noob in C programming. Could you please ellaborate your answer. How can I pack the `src` into a byte array of size `6` which starts from the `byte[2]` of the `src` without masking?

Comment: @M.Denis You never mentioned that you have byte array of size 6.

Comment: @M.Denis The question says you want to put it in a `uint48_t`. There's no byte array in the question, so what does that have to do with it?

Comment: @kiranBiradar Sorry, I have edited the question now.

Comment: @Barmar I have one more question. The `buffer[0]` contains the MSB of the 48 bit number yeah?

Comment: Yes. When `i = 0`, `48 - 8 * i == 48`, so we do `bytes[0] == (value >> 48) & 0xff`

Comment: Oops, that's wrong, we want to shift by 40 for the MSB, I'm off by 1.

Comment: Fixed it now, it should be `40 - 8 * i`

Comment: The `& 0xffffffffffff;` in `uint48_t answer = src & 0xffffffffffff;` in unnecessary - even if the 2 MSBytes of `src` are non-zero.

Comment: @chux Perhaps, but it doesn't hurt to be explicit. The optimizer should notice that it's redundant and not generate any extra code.

Answer (score 1):

Make a union with your uint64_t value and an array of Bytes.

```
typefef union
{
    uint8_t   ByteArray[8];
    uint64_t  Value;
}Array64T;

Array64T   CompleteValue;

CompleteValue.Value = ...
```

Comment: Doesn't type punning like this cause undefined behavior?

Comment: For example, this is dependent on whether the CPU is big-endian or little-endian.

Comment: yes of course its endian dependend but I didn' see any UB.

Comment: You're only allowed to read the last member of a union that you wrote.

Comment: @Barmarbar no union punning is safe. See the gcc dev discussions

Answer (score 1):

```
void *copt6lsb(uint64_t val, void *buff)
{
    union{
        uint8_t d8[2];
        uint16_t d16;
    }u16 = {.d8[0] = 0xff};
    char *pos = &val;

    pos = pos + 2 * (u16.d16 == 0xff00);
    memcpy(buff, pos, 6);
    return buff;
}
```

Good thing is that most compilers then the optimization is on will optimize out the union and will replace the comparison with assignment.

https://godbolt.org/z/JKXDC2

and platforms which allow unaligned access will optimize the memcpy as well

https://godbolt.org/z/c3_ypL